# Regular expression: at least one blank space enclosed by any character

Tags: regex, validation

I'd like to force my users to have at least two words in a string divided by a blank space.

Allowed is any string that has at least one blank space enclosed by at least one character to the left and to the right. No blank space on the front and no blank space at the end.

Some examples:

- John Doe (valid)
- John Walter Doe (valid)
- John (not valid)
- John $ole (valid)
- 3d3n 1snt f4r (valid)
- John the 3rd (valid)
- Jöning Wölter (valid)
- Joe Garçon (valid)
- Harald Spaß (valid)

Just FYI: I want to use this for a very weak full name check. Since there are MANY special characters that can occur in names, I simply want my users to force to have at least two words in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement, it's translated like this in regex:

```
^\S+\s+.*\S$
```

If you want your white space to be just " ", then use

```
^\S+ +.*\S$
```

But be careful that you make cultural assumptions here. Real names don't follow strict rules.

Comment: Well I guess it's common to have at least a first and a last name. Isn't it?

Comment: It's common, yes. Doesn't mean it's a rule. TBH this regex is much more reasonable than what we usually see in this context.

Comment: This solution uses .* which can be hideous for performance. It will also match on **any** whitespace so newlines, tabs etc

Comment: @tmuecksch worth reading: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41153/best-regex-for-first-last-name-validation and http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @DenysSéguret thanks. Thats indeed very helpful knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This matches a word followed by one or more groups of whitespace + word

```
/^\S+(\s+\S+)+$/
```

It does match **any** whitespace though so perhaps

```
/^\S+( +\S+)+$/
```

would be better

Comment: It allows blank blank spaces on the front and at the end. Could you change your answer in order to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
^(\S+)(\s{1}\S+)+$
```

Comment: Why do you put parenthesis around the first word ?

Comment: my bad. it was simply to distinguish the two different patterns, but it's pretty useless